# What is the difference between <article> and <section> in html5

Tags: html

When should I use `<article>` and `<section>` tags in HTML5?

Comment: What is your special programming problem?

Comment: you want some kind of cheat sheet. look here or some other place to look it up once yoy get confused again http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html

Comment: Hope this link help for your requirement:http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-section-article-elements/

Comment: Since when can't questions be about language/markup features which are causing confusion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `<section>` tag:

> The section tag defines sections in a document, such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document.

The `<article>` tag:

> The article tag specifies independent, self-contained content.
>
> An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to
>   distribute it independently from the rest of the site.
>
> Potential sources for the article element:
>
> - Forum post
> - Blog post
> - News story
> - Comment

Basically these tags are *semantic elements* and the only real difference between them are readability and design preference.

You can read more about them here if you wish:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp

Comment: How does this relate to, say, React components?  Would you consider the term "Component" to be closer in meaning to `article` or `section`?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I think of the concept of React components as simply a container for different kinds of data. These HTML5 tags are just semantic ways of describing that data, so they're kind of unrelated to React components and more related to the content

Comment: Oh yes I understand; this was more of a thought exercise.  When building apps that have little in common with documents/blogs (or "articles") it can be difficult to pick semantically correct HTML5 tags.

Comment: Your definition of the section tag is circular. It is not exactly defined what *section of the document* really is and what it is not.

Answer (score 11):

**Article tag**

> The article tag is used for wrapping an autonomous content on a page.
>   A content is autonomous if it can be removed from the page and put on
>   some another page.

**Section tag**

> The section tag is similar to the div tag, but it is more meaningful
>   since it wraps logical groups of related content (e.g. a chapter of an
>   article).

More about semantic tags -
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/semantic-html

Comment: @vijayscode- Your explanation is awesome

Comment: nice answer, I just added some missing info about headigs in the section tag, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@vijayscode's answer is crystal clear, I just add quotes of the standard and a real world example.

### [section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element)

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading. **A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) emphasizes the heading presence even more:

> Sections should always have a heading, with very few exceptions.

### [article](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element)

> The article element represents a **complete, or self-contained**, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, **independently distributable or reusable**, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

### So what is the difference?

Look at sections *Must see*, *Most watched*, *Full story* on [BBC news](https://www.bbc.com/news) - they could be **sections** (albeit in the source they currently use more generic divs), they contain a heading and photo & link blocks which target to the main content somewhere else, so their meaning depends on other parts of the site. When you click on some of them, you land on a page that in its main content contains an **article**. It can exist independently to the rest of the site.

Complex articles can contain sections (like Perex, Conclusion or Sources). And sections can contain multiple short articles.

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding <article>

The HTML 5 spec defines <article>:

> "The article element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content."

Let's distill the essentials:

> *The article element is a self-contained composition that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication.*

The definition is somewhat abstract, so let's explore it comprehensively, bit by bit.

**'self-contained'**

This refers to the nature of the content being 'complete' in some sense.  Which could mean either:

1. The content doesn't rely on external content to be understood.
2. The element includes all components necessary for its purpose.

For instance, a news article or a blog post typically has all the information needed for a reader to understand its message or story without needing to reference other parts of the site.  Also, each article bundles the components necessary for its purpose, including title, author, publication date, etc.

**'in principle'**

This suggests a certain degree of idealization and flexibility in the definition.  It implies that *'independently distributable or reusable'* covers typical or ideal use cases, acknowledging that there can be exceptions or variations in real-world applications.  In other words, *'independently distributable or reusable'* is more of a *guiding concept* or *rough litmus test* than a rigid rule, meaning other kinds of content can also benefit from being marked up as <article>.

**'independently'**

Means either:

1. Makes sense on its own.  [ *compare with 'self-contained' (1)* ]
2. Exists coherently outside the context in which it appears.  [ *compare with 'self-contained (2)* ]

For instance, a news article doesn't rely on other parts of the page to convey a complete report or story.  The same is true of a blog post, which introduces, discusses, and closes on a topic or idea.  Either can appear on a different website or platform and still be a coherent entity.  In contrast, the <footer> of a news or blog post, which may contain links for further reading, end notes, citations, and so on, cannot be understood independently; it would be missing other components necessary for its purpose (such as the main content, title, etc.).

**'distributable'**

That is to say: distributable across different platforms or contexts.

For instance, a product card, which displays product information in a concise way ...

[image: Example of Product Card]

... can be embedded in different websites, in mobile apps, or in email marketing materials while retaining its functionality and design integrity.  News articles and blog posts can be syndicated among different publications, and might be referenced on social media platforms where they're relevant to discussions people are having.

**'reusable'**

In web design, *'reusable'* often refers to modular design.  This is a slightly different from 'distributable', in which the same product card can appear on different websites and platforms.  Rather, the product card *template* can appear multiple times on the same e-commerce site (e.g. across different categories of products and in search results), without needing a redesign.  The same template can handle different types of images, descriptions, pricing information, and so on.

**'e.g. syndication'**

This usually refers to the distribution of content beyond the original website.  But note that 'e.g.' means 'for example'.   Here, *'syndication'* is provided as an illustrative example of 'distributable *or* reusable' (it just so happens to be an example of the *former* and not the *latter*).

The upshot is that an <article> is not *necessarily* syndicatable; if it's 'reusable' in any other straightforward sense (e.g. modular) then it may still qualify as an <article>.

**Let's analyze the other concrete examples listed in the spec …**

The inclusion of forum posts and user comments as examples of 'self-contained' compositions might initially seem counterintuitive.  They often rely on the surrounding context for full understanding, and this includes the original post as well as the broader thread.  By including these examples, the HTML5 specification is highlighting the flexibility of its definition, accomodating diverse web content practices, even those that are not perfectly ideal, so as not to restrict the use of the <article> element too narrowly.

**It's not difficult to see why forum posts and user submitted comments should be marked up with <article>.**

Despite the semi-independent nature, a user post / comment is 'self-contained' in terms of its authorship and the point(s) the author decides to make.  The element includes all the components necessary for its purpose: to encapsulate a user's complete thought or response, which contributes individually to a discussion.  Since comment sections usually host multiple comments from different users, the reusability of the element's basic structure as a template is self-evident in this case.

Lastly, in digital journalism and blogging, highlighting user comments as standalone articles is becoming more common, reflecting the growing importance of user-generated content in online discourse.  Sometimes a post or comment can be especially insightful, humorous, or newsworthy, while largely standing on its own.  Other websites or publications might reference these individual posts in their content to highlight a specific point or to showcase user opinions or reactions.

**MDN Example**

MDN has an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article) of <article> used in a nested fashion:

[image: MDN Example]

Each day's forecast is a self-contained piece of information with a date and a weather description, making it a distinct unit within the overall forecast.  The example illustrates how segments of an article can still function as self-contained units (articles themselves).  While it might not be common, there's a theoretical possibility that each day's forecast could be individually referenced or shared. For example, a user might want to share just one day's forecast with someone planning an event on that specific day.

### Understanding <section>

Contrary to the <article> element, the <section> element in HTML5 serves a more organizational purpose.  It's not meant to represent self-contained content, but rather to structure a document into thematic groupings or segments of a larger narrative or structure.  In essence, while <article> is about the content itself, <section> is about how that content is organized.  Let's explore some examples that illustrate the versatility of <section>:

**UI elements where <section> aids in segmenting different functional areas, grouping articles together:**

- On a news website, different categories like 'World News', 'Sports', and 'Entertainment' are organized under <section> tags, each encompassing a group of relevant articles.
- A list of recommended content creators.
- A panel of app control buttons.

**Text-oriented use of <section> within <article> for segmenting content into digestable chunks:**

- In an extensive tutorial, each <section> could represent a phase comprising a group of related steps. These sections contribute to the overall narrative but are not standalone pieces.
- In an academic textbook or an eBook, chapters or thematic divisions could be marked as <section>, where each part adds to a cumulative understanding but is not independent.
- A long-form blog post might use <section> elements to organize its content into an introduction, detailed analysis, and conclusion.

**The Importance of Headings**

A <section> often benefits from a heading (<h1> `—` <h6>) to provide context, depending on the document's structure.

For instance, in a long-form web article, each section might start with a heading that summarizes its content:

[image: Headings for sections.]

Even a web UI <section> can benefit from a heading, helping users grasp the collective significance of its items:

[image: A heading for a group of share buttons.]

This practice not only improves readability but can assist in navigation, especially for assistive technologies.  MDN recommends :

> "each <section> should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1 - h6 element) as a child of the <section> element, wherever possible." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

MDN allows for exceptions where it makes sense:

> "Circumstances where you might see <section> used without a heading are typically found in web application/UI sections rather than in traditional document structures." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

**Final notes on <section>**

In summary, an <article> can contain <section> elements to organize its content and conversely, a <section> can encompass multiple <article> elements grouped together.  Headings are often helpful in clarifying scope and significance.

Of all the sectioning elements introduced in HTML5 (which include <nav>, <aside>, <article>, and <section>), <section> is the most generic and should only be used if none of the others' semantics apply.  Also, remember that <section> is a *semantic* element; it should not be used purely as a hook for styling or scripting - that's what <div> is for.

### Conclusion

The concept of the <article> element, while seemingly elusive, is inherently straightforward and versatile.  Having absorbed the information presented and reflected upon it, you should now possess a solid base for intuitively determining when to utilize <article>.  This foundational understanding enables you to critically assess and appreciate others' interpretations and simplifications, such as Bruce Lawson's analogy:

> "Consider the <article> not merely as a newspaper article or a blog post, but akin to an article of clothing — a distinct item capable of being repurposed in different contexts. For instance, trousers are an article, adaptable to various outfits; a shirt is another, pairable with different trousers; and so are knee-length patent leather stiletto boots (which, naturally, are worn in pairs)." - [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/html5-article-section/#comments-html5-article-section)

In contrast, a <section> is exactly what its name suggests - a distinct segment or division within a content structure.

It's worth remembering that the HTML5 specifications serve as guiding principles rather than precise rules.  They offer a framework for comprehending the application of different elements, yet they do not encompass every nuance or unique scenario. Consequently, web developers are often called upon to exercise their judgment, informed by the specific content and context at hand.  Decisions regarding the use of <article> often hinge on one's interpretation of the content's independence and completeness.

Bruce Lawson, a notable figure in the field of web standards, even [suggests avoiding <section> altogether](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/html5-article-section/#comments-html5-article-section), which suggests that its benefits, particularly in terms of SEO, accessibility, or behavior, might be marginal. Therefore, navigating the gray area between <article> and <section> is unlikely to incur significant repercussions. The key is to let practical considerations and common sense guide your decisions, remembering that there are no 'HTML police' to enforce strict adherence to these guidelines.

I think developers should use <section>.  Even though sectioning elements were initially envisioned to play a significant role in the now defunct 'document outline algorithm', their semantics remain useful for constructing more structured, meaningful HTML, which, if not for potential future ways they may be leveraged by search engines, assistive technologies, and other automated tools, then for improved readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the example of this page,
The question can be wrapped in one section tag, answers in another, and composing new answer in another section tag.
In the answers section, each answer can be inside an article tag.
So, the section is used to define sections of the page, while an article is generally used for wrapping similar content, like, each blogpost in a list of blog posts.
Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above: let's take a movie as an example. The movie itself would be the article whereas each scene would be a section.

Answer (score 0):

**section tag**

> When you just want to decorate any content on your page i.e. you want
> to add some functions then you can use  tag, which also can
> be replaced by the  tag. The section tag will be good when the
> content of any web page is appropriate for the contents outline and
> browsers do not give any attention to the outlines.

**article tag**

> The  tag is a self-completed tag, this can be used for any of
> those reasons, where  tag is required plus the  tag
> place the content independently. Article tag can be used to place any
> social post, magazine article, blog, list of related contents, any
> independent content

If your content material contains the date, price, author, description, etc then go for the article tag. Basically use an article tag to contain content that could be shared and obviously for actual articles. Wrap your blog posts in them.

If your content contains any kind of procedure to make or create something that will depend on something then go for the section tag like a div, when it describes what your document outline would include.